# Why does current remain constant in a conductor having non-uniform cross section for constant voltage supply if I=neAvd?

Tags: electricity

I am confused in this question:

> A copper wire of non-uniform area of cross-section is connected to a d.c. battery. The physical quantity which remains constant along the wire is …

At first I thought this way:
Since $I=neAv_\mathrm d$
Where $I$ is current, $n$ is number density of free electrons, $A$ is area of cross section and $v_\mathrm d$ is average drift velocity of electrons in the conductor.
So from this relation one can easily see that current is directly proportional to area of cross section. So current should increase with increase in area of cross section. But it wasn't the explanation.

Its answer is given as current, that is **current remains constant**, and the explanation is provided as:
"Current is defined as charge flown per unit time, it should remain same along any cross section as there is no accumulation of charge in conductor. Hence current will remain constant."

I don't understand when to employ $I=neAv_\mathrm d$ and when to apply definition of current.

Comment: At the constant current, A.vd is constant. It has direct analogy with water flowing through a pipe with variable diameter. A narrower tube means faster flow.

Comment: Yep, just what the comment above said. It's the principle of continuity in fluids, analogously applied for current.

Comment: Also, isn't this question more suitable for physics stack exchange than chemistry stack exchange?

Comment: Even if chemistry is in this or that way involved in majority of domains from astronomy to psychology, for most of these domains there is better to ask somebody else than chemists. This is such a case, even if trivial enough so chemists can answer it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to consider that $v_\text{d} \propto \frac 1A$.

A place with a narrower wire means there is stronger intensity of electric field, causing faster electron drift motion, compensating for smaller cross-section area.

Initially, when such a wire is just being attached to an external voltage, the intensity of the field is the same along the wire. But, as it causes smaller current at the wire bottleneck, there is being formed very tiny excess and deficit of electrons at the respective narrow place ends.

This deviation causes additional electrostatic field, making electrons moving faster, leading to the same current as for the rest of the wire.

You probably know the Ohm law

$$U=RI,$$

what is the relation of the current and the voltage (potential difference). But this is its integral, macroscopic form.

The Ohm law has also its equivalent, differential form, valid locally at any wire point.

$$\vec E [\pu{Vm-1}]=\sigma [\pu{\Omega m}] \vec j[\pu{Am-2}]$$

where sigma as material resistivity (generally a tensor, but effectively a scalar for isotropic materials) is the proportionality constant between vectors of current density $\vec j$ and electrostatic field intensity $\vec E$.

---

Similarly, for the water pipe analogy mentioned in the comment, the narrow pipe passage causes a local increase of hydrostatic pressure gradient, that causes pushing the same water flow even through smaller pipe cross-section.

Answer (score 1):

The current is the number of electrons crossing a given section of the conducting wire per second. It does not depend on the importance of this section or of the position of this section along the wire. This wire can be thin or wide. The number of electrons crossing any part of the circuit or any section of the wire per second is always the same. One mole electrons crossing any section of the wire per second is $96500$ Ampere, whatever the diameter of the wire.